# CodeIgniter template engine view syntax {}

Tags: codeigniter, templates, view

I have CodeIgniter project and need to change view. there is unusual way to display content in view. It doesn't use any loop. Instead of it is written, like this:

```
{news}
//Some html code 
{/news}.
```

Do anyone know what template engine does it uses? And how it works?

Comment: Go through the documentation https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html

Comment: Codeigniter uses its own template engine. Simply use $this->parse-> in the controller

Comment: Thanks very much. Now I got how it works with help of you. I have one more question.. In my controller I have no $this->parse->... Here it is how to is written. I don't understand where the header() function is. 
 $this->template->header();
 $this->template->page('news');
 $this->template->footer();